# Xamarin.Forms: Cropping image into circle with frame doesnt clip fully

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a rectangle for a photo and I am trying to crop a circle out of it

```
                        <Frame x:Name="circleFrame" 
                               Grid.Column="0"      
                               BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                               WidthRequest="50"
                               HeightRequest="50" 
                               CornerRadius="25"
                               IsClippedToBounds="True"
                               HasShadow="False" 
                               Padding="0"
                               Margin="0,10,10,10" 
                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                            <Image
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                WidthRequest="1000"
                                HeightRequest="1000"
                                Source="{Binding thumbnailSource}"/>
                        </Frame>
```

While this does clip the image ever so slightly, the image is still centered. I tried to just increase the size of the image by a lot to get the image to clip fully, but this is the result:

[image]

Please see the picture with the "n k" next to it. Youll see that the thumbnail is clipped on the sides but not fully on the top and bottom.

How can I

a.) increase the size of the image

OR

b.) use a different technique to crop a circle out of the center of the image?

Thank you

Comment: have u tried aspect = fill ? in the ImageView ?

Comment: Would you care for an answer ? Cause that was correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Use -

```
Aspect="AspectFill"
```

In your ImageView

also when you give fillandexpand you dont have to specify height and width,
height and width willl be applicable when you will use center